# How do I programmatically tell the computer to trigger a keydown of the letter q?

Tags: javascript, triggers, keydown

I am simply trying to fire three q keydown strokes on a called function

> function threeqs(){*fire three q strokes*}

Comment: Use dispatchEvent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: can you write a specific example to use for the letter q?

Comment: Note that the keydown events would only be able to be applied to the page content.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can programmaticaly fire events by using `EventTarget.dispatchEvent(event)`

You could write something like this to fire your event three times:

```
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```js
var element = document.createElement("p");
element.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'q'}));

function logKey(e) {

//Do your stuff
console.log(e.key);
 
}
```

Comment: can you please provide an example?

Comment: im getting a boolean when assigning to a variable.

Comment: I have attached a small example to the original answer, hope that helps!

Comment: is this just logging the letter q? I am trying to accomplish pressing the q button three times without touching the keyboard The capture of the letter q is exactly right, but instead of console, I want the the letter to be pressed as if I were typing without actually typing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'q'}))
```

Comment: https://repl.it/@MathewStratton1/WelloffClutteredTriggers#index.php

Comment: Im trying to switch to the second div to start the timer by pressing the q button twice, I put your code in twice consecutively in the freckleMeTonsForBurnCooknessOntheGrillSet() function and it did not work. if you see the repl, and click Apes, and the Begin with undefined, and then manually press q twice. the clock will start, but the idea is to have the computer programmatically cue  two q buttons so the clock starts.

Comment: can you please provide an example? im getting a boolean when i console log this